# How to get input value in TextInputField and PasswordInput in flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I have a UI copied from Github and there are some input fields as follows:

```
Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [

               TextInputField(
                  controller:_username,
                  icon: FontAwesomeIcons.envelope,
                  hint: 'username',
                  inputType: TextInputType.text,
                   onChanged: (value){
                     //set username  text on change
                     print(value);
                     username = value;
                   }
                ),
              PasswordInput(
                controller: _password,
                icon: FontAwesomeIcons.lock,
                hint: 'Password',
                inputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                onChanged: (value){
                  // change password text
                  print(value);
                  password = value;
                },

              ),
```

In the above code i added two arguments one is `controller` and other one is `onChanged` but when I print the value ii print nothing also there is two more dart files for the same like `text-input-field.dart` :

```
class TextInputField extends StatelessWidget {const TextInputField({
Key key,
@required this.icon,
@required this.hint,
this.inputType,
this.inputAction, TextEditingController controller, onChanged, }) : super(key: key);

final IconData icon;
final String hint;
final TextInputType inputType;
final TextInputAction inputAction;
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
   return Padding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
   child: Container(
    height: size.height * 0.08,
    width: size.width * 0.8,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.grey[500].withOpacity(0.5),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
    ),
    child: Center(
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          prefixIcon: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
            child: Icon(
              icon,
              size: 28,
              color: kWhite,
            ),
          ),
          hintText: hint,
          hintStyle: kBodyText,
        ),
        style: kBodyText,
        keyboardType: inputType,
        textInputAction: inputAction,
      ),
    ),
    ),
   );
   }
   }
```

and there is similar file `password-input.dart`

**I want to get the value of that input field can anyone tell me how?**

Comment: can you show me your controllers for the field

Answer (score 0):

Values of text fields are accessible from controller :

e.g. You can get username value from `_username.text`.

Comment: i tried bro but its not working

Comment: Did you define controllers out of build method ? Pls add this to question that where did you define controllers.